# how to rename function after definition

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcc, linker

I want to implement unit testing using the `-Wl,--wrap` trick, however this doesn't work for functions within the same file. One solution is to rename the function (after it has been defined) to the wrapped one, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11758777/526568

I came up with the following macro to avoid having to manually define `__wrap_foo`:

```
#define UNIT_TEST_SYMBOL(x) \
    typeof(x) __wrap_##x __attribute__((weak, alias(#x)))

void foo(void) {
    /* function body */
}
UNIT_TEST_SYMBOL(foo);

#define foo __wrap_foo

void bar(void) {
    foo();
}
```

I then compile with `-Wl,--wrap=foo`.

Is it possible to avoid having to manually define `foo` to `__wrap_foo`? Can this be somehow part of the `UNIT_TEST_SYMBOL`?

Comment: https://github.com/Guardsquare/mocxx

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin does it work for plain old C?

Comment: Also mocxx fails to build.

Comment: I think, since local functions in the same translation unit are resolved at compile time, the linker has no chance to intercept. I would try to work on the source level, perhaps with some kind of separated preprocessing tool. Another idea is to separate the functions in different translation units.

Comment: However, unit testing is about testing the **_unit_**. And I think that local functions are just a part of a unit, and should therefore not be tested in isolation. -- This is a common misunderstanding in my eyes, to test functions, and not functionality, vulgo requirements. -- You might like to consider to post your use case to help us understand the issue.

Comment: @thebusybee It depends on how you define the "unit", it's not set to stone that a unit is the source file. In Python you can trivially mock and unit test functions _within_ the same source file.