# Does accesing .text segment via `extern` variables cause undefined-behaviour?

Tags: c, undefined, undefined-behavior

This is file "1.c"

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    char foo;
    int bar(){
    }
    int main(){
        printf("%d",foo);
        return 0;
    }
    //--------------------------
```

This is file '2.c'

```
    void foo(){
    }
```

Compiler invoked as `gcc 1.c 2.c`

Does the above gives an undefined behaviour? My guess is, **yes**. Otherwise it's almost impossible to do optimization.

> > Multiple different definitions for the same entity (class, template, enumeration, inline function, static member function, etc.) [What are all the common undefined behaviour that a C++ programmer should know about?

But as far as I know `char foo` produce only a **weak symbol** that can be overridden by *void foo(){}* at linkage. Furthermore, if I change `char foo` into `extern char foo`, is that still a **definition**?

Comment: Discussion of things like weak symbols goes beyond the scope of the C standard (and therefore it's not necessarily meaningful to ask whether "undefined behaviour" applies here)...

Comment: extern char foo would only be a declaration and no definition. You can try to add it in 1.c (without 2.c), it should throws error during compilation

Comment: I think you can get answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766022/linking-libraries-with-duplicate-class-names-using-gcc"Here"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd cause undefined behaviour, yes. There are probably lots of quotes from the standard that are explicit for the various types of declarations and so forth, but this sums it up:

> In the set of translation units and libraries that constitutes an entire program, each
> declaration of a particular identiﬁer with external linkage denotes the same object or
> function. (6.2.2)
>
> All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type;
> otherwise, the behavior is undeﬁned. (6.2.7)

`char foo;` in your example is a tentative definition. If you use `extern`, it would not be a definition, but it'd still be a declaration, and the above would still apply.